# django inconsistent id and date for the same query, why?

Tags: python, django

I have next model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

And my data something like :

```
id    name    date
120   john    9-11-2011 19:00:25
121   john    9-11-2011 19:05:55
....
180   steven  10-11-2011 00:00:45
...
468    cleve  10-11-2011 23:55:35
```

In views.py

-When I try this :

```
dates=[]
ids=[]
for i in People.objects.filter(date__range=["2011-11-10", "2011-11-11"]):
    ids.append(i.id)
    dates.append(i.date)
return HttpResponse("ids=%s  dates=%s"% (ids,dates))
```

So, I have a very basic orm query to filter one days' data. The code has a weird problem, because the ids should be `ids=[180...468],` 
but it returns

```
ids=[120...408]
dates=[datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 10, 0, 0, 45), ....datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 10, 23, 55, 35)
```

The thing is the dates that the code returns are correct, however the ids are not correct. How is this possible, why i am getting inconsistent id and date for the same query ?

Comment: You really should be filtering your dates with datetime.datetime object

Comment: Maybe your data doesn't look like you think? With the above code, the last entry in ids clearly comes from the same table row that the last entry in dates.

Comment: Is it a potential timezone issue where the dates are interpreted differently from the database and how they are rendered by Django?

Comment: @Aea, I tried datetime.datetime object as well. But, still getting same results.

Comment: @AustinPhillips, if yes, so what is the solution ?

Comment: You haven't shown how the data is being printed in either the database list or the Django code.  Look for any locations where time zone conversion could occur such as when outputting a date in a Django template.  Look at the [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones) documentation for Django. (If using Django 1.4)

Comment: @AustinPhillips, i updated the dates that i printed in django. The data is already converted from string to datetimefield. But, the format is a kinda different instead of 2011, 11, 10, 0, 0, 45, it is like 10-11-2011 00:00:45. Does it matter ?

Comment: Sorry, haven't got much time to reply.  How about just trying a query on a single record. `person = People.objects.get(id=120)` and verify that all the `person` attributes match what you are expecting.

Comment: @AustinPhillips I did it, and interestingly it returns:id=120 date= 10-11-2011 00:00:45, it does not match, I will be crazy, how is this possible ?

Comment: @AustinPhillips, i think you are so right, the problem is timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the greater than / less than filters:

```
for i in People.objects.filter(date__lte='2011-11-10').filter(date__gte='2011-11-11'):
    ...
```

Comment: Tried that one, but still getting same results.